# Phonegap: Splashscreen does not work

Tags: android, cordova, netbeans, splash-screen

I am making an Android app using HTML5 on Netbeans IDE. I am using the Cordova framweork to build. Until now, everything is OK except, I cannot make the splashscreen works.

I consulted the Phonegap documentations but in vain. Here what I did below:

- The splashscreen plugin is already added in the Cordova plugins
  section on Netbeans IDE.
- I put the PNG images in the *platforms/android/res/drawable*/* folders.
- I checked the parameters of the splashscreen in the XML Config file
  which is located in *res/xml/config.xml*. It seems the parameters
  are OK just like on the documentation.
- I included the configurations in the XML Config file which is located in the WWW folder.
- And finally, I copied and pasted the JavaScript codes in my
  index.html file in the Head section just like on the documentation as
  shown below:

  ```
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    function onDeviceReady() {
      navigator.splashscreen.show();
  }
  ```

Here are the two Phonegap documentations links:

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_splashscreen_splashscreen.md.html
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/config_ref_images.md.html#Icons%20and%20Splash%20Screens

So, where is the mistake? Thank!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to set this -

```
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="splash" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="10000" />
```

in config.xml